# Replace function asking for argument in oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to run below query

```
SELECT     REPLACE('SURES&npsp','&npsp', 'H')  FROM DUAL
```

When i run it's asking two inputs for both the above **'&npsp'**.
Actually my requirement is to replace **'&npsp'** with **'H'**.
Is there any other way of doing this replace.

Comment: While Gary_W does provide a solution that works for the scenario you identified, perhaps using DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT function might be a more robust approach.  Here is an example of this approach, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89939/html-entity-decoding-with-oracle-dbms-xmlgen-convert

Comment: @PatrickBacon - `&npsp` isn't an entity though? Or have I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right. I mistook it for `&nbsp`. Could this be a typo error? If we are not replacing entities, then my suggestion will not work...agreed.

Comment: @PatrickBacon - there's no semicolon either, and replacing `&nbsp;` with an H would be a bit odd. But who knows, it could just be garbled in posting...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the extra replacement prompts you're getting, just execute

```
set define off;
```

before running the query.

Comment: That assumes the OP is running the query as a script. @sureshhh If you're running it as a standalone statement in a GUI (eg. Toad, SQL Developer, etc) there is usually an option to turn the substitution variable prompting off somewhere in the tool (eg. in Toad, you would right mouse click on the editor window and select the relevant option).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to break `&` from characters:

```
SELECT     REPLACE('SURES&'||'npsp','&'||'npsp', 'H')  FROM DUAL
```

Solution is not better than `set define off`, but I am able to remember it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Informatica solution, you can use `REPLACESTR(1, 'SURES&npsp','&npsp', 'H')`